# A weird situation about matching in flex

Tags: compiler-construction, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

I am writing a scanner in flex, and I have the following two definitions:

```
%%
"int" printf("JUST_INT");
"int"[ \t\n]+"matrix" printf("MATRIX_INT");
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*  printf("IDENTIFIER");
%%
```

When the input to the scanner is `int matrixM = 3;` the output is `MATRIX_INT IDENTIFIER`. It sees the input as `int matrix M=3`. But actually, this is not a `matrix`, the name of identifier is `matrixM`. Output should be `JUST_INT IDENTIFIER`. Why is this happening? Is that because of my definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good idea to have rules that scan across spaces like `"int"[ \t\n]+"matrix"`. Just return "int", "matrix", and IDENTIFIER as three separate tokens and let the parser sort it out. It's much better at that than `flex` is. `flex` just does the first longest match.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to solve this at the scanner level, you can match on

```
"int"[ \t\n]+"matrix"/($|[ \t\n]|;|whateverelsedelimitsanidentifier)
```

This makes sure that `matrix` is only matched if it is followed by a "non-word".  As EJP said, it is not a good idea however and you should do this very probably at the parser level instead.